# ios file write is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I want to write a simple data in file it is not working.

```
- (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)aString {

    // Build the path, and create if needed.
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = @"bookmark.json";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSLog(@"%@",fileAtPath);
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    // The main act...
    [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Your code looks good to me, however there is no error reporting.  Use `[NSData writeToFile:options:error:]` and check the return code and log the error object.

Comment: Why do you have that `if` statement and why are you calling `createFileAtPath`? You don't need either. Just call `writeToFile:options:error:`.

Comment: hi did not find any file name bookmark.json

Answer (score 0):

You can anyway modify the documents directory of your application.

**Check if a File Exists at a Path Or NOT**

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 //Get documents directory
 NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
 (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@""]==YES) {
     NSLog(@"File exists");
 }
```

**Check if Writable, Readable, and Executable**

```
if ([fileManager isWritableFileAtPath:@"FilePath"]) {
    NSLog(@"isWritable");
 }
 if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:@"FilePath"]) {
    NSLog(@"isReadable");
 }
 if ( [fileManager isExecutableFileAtPath:@"FilePath"]){
    NSLog(@"is Executable");
 }
```

**Try This One**  [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_file_handling.htm)

**Happy Coding (^_^)**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

```
  - (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)aString {

// Build the path, and create if needed.
NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName = @"bookmark.json";
NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSLog(@"%@",fileAtPath);
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
    // The main act...
[[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:YES];
}}
```

Comment: So it doesn't write the string if the file exists?  And it doesn't detect and report errors.  It's worse that the OPs code.

Comment: can use [NSData writeToFile:options:error:] instead...!

Comment: Yeah I know.  However I am commenting on what your code actually demonstrates.